# Monitoring Domain Connectivity Status

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, network-programming, dns

Is there any way to monitor the availability of a domain, when the server is unknown at runtime? `NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`, does not provide consistent results across framework versions/operating systems.

I'm dealing with mobile units on a domain, that are going to consistently lose and re-acquire domain connectivity; and I need to detect in code, when this happens.

I've tried Google, Bing, and MSDN and come up with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using p/Invoke [NetWkstaUserGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370670%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[System.Environment.UserDomainName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) gets data from environment variable.

Comment: Sort of, an initial connection requires you to reboot, but the problem remains if you disconnect from an already connected domain (which does not require a reboot), and then reconnect (which also does not require a reboot). The problem I have, I'm dealing with many machines, on different domains, so I have no clue which server to query.

Comment: I think you are not clear of what you want as you think computers are changing domain. Though possible its very unlikely.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for more of a change in domain status, than change in domain name to be more accurate. I have mobile units that fall on and off a domain (due to loss of connectivity), they do not  need to reboot to rejoin that domain, but the domain is not available. The problem is, different mobile units, are on different domains, and I don't which domain to query. The domain name, changes on XP machines, to null, on Vista/7 later machines, it changes to their workgroup, is the observed behaviour when they lose connectivity, so I was hoping to be able to check/query that.

Comment: @Brain What method do you use to see domain name? It surprising it returns null.

Comment: System.Environment.UserDomainName

Comment: can you try using p/Invoke NetWkstaUserGetInfo System.Environment.UserDomainName gets data from environment variable.

Comment: also edit the question that domain name is not changed its connection that broken

Comment: That worked, Rohit, if you go ahead and post that as an official answer, I'll upvote and accept it. I'll also edit the question to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the [`System.Environment.UserDomainName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) property?

Comment: I know how to find the domain I'm connected to, I need to monitor when it changes is the problem.

Comment: I guess you'd have to do some polling, since it's a static property of a static class, otherwise you could override it and fire an event from the setter.

Comment: yeah, that's why I was curious if there was any other code, such as in Directory Services, or one of the System.Net or System.Web spaces or something that let me monitor it; I just wasn't aware of any and before I got a manual solution approved, wanted to double check myself.

Comment: I do not know of any Win version that can change domain without reboot.