# How do i tell if a computer is domain joined?

Tags: c#, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if machine is joined to domain (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c)

Is there any way to tell if a computer is joined to a domain or not without using any external DLL's? I dont care about the name of the domain, just if it is joined or not.. like a boolean value.

Thanks in advance.
Dan

Comment: Not a duplicate, that answer is to use an external DLL. I am looking if there is a way to do that without external DLL's

Comment: That answer uses the Win32 DLL's. Any solution you find in .NET will use those same DLLs at their core. Why not just use them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me, not on the previous post, is using p/Invoke NetWkstaUserGetInfo.

Depending on the details of your situation, the other post's suggestions won't work (cross-operating system returns different values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755701/monitoring-domain-connectivity-status

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.UserDomainName` will give you your domain name

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx)

> Use the UserDomainName property to obtain the user's domain name

so you don't need external dll :)